# Sheets - Dropdown list based on items value

Tags: arrays, validation, google-sheets, filter, dropdown

In google sheets from the table with items and its availability, I'd like to create a drop down list in a way to see only available items - so as in example on the drop down list i'd like to see Items A,B and E only, preferably with the corresponding quantity.

[image: drop down table]

Comment: take a look at this https://www.bpwebs.com/how-to-create-a-dependent-drop-down-list-in-google-sheet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this formula in Z column and create dropdown via data validation from there referencing Z column (then you can hide whole Z column > right click on column > hide)

```
=FILTER(A2:A; B2:B>0)
```

Comment: Works great, any chance to add the value of the corresponding column B next to the items from column A visible at the drop down list ?

Comment: sure, try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(A2:A&" ("&B2:B&")"; B2:B>0))`